# Monitorando REST API status

Tags: python, api, rest

Eu estou aprendendo e tentando resolver um caso de um POST *request* em que é feito um envio de um *body* bem largo para ser processado pela API e o retorno é um *job* ID para acessar o resultado.

Acontece que o tempo que a API leva para processar pode variar consoante o tamanho do *body* e tenho de verificar o status do *job* com outra GET *request* usando o *job* ID para saber do seu status. Se o status for complete então eu posso fazer o download do resultado `ficheiro.zip` via por exemplo `URLlib.retrieve()` ou algo parecido.

Qual seria a melhor forma de monitorar os vários POST *requests* enviados para saber se o seu estado está completo e se sim fazer o download.

Procuro padrão, boa prática ou até mesmo algum modulo para importar que ajude.

Comment: sua pergunta não está muito clara, mas de qualquer forma: você já ouviu falar de `celery`?

Comment: Nao ainda nao ouvi nada sobre celery. Talvez o tipo API em causa ajude veja link no final . o que se pretende é interrogar periodicamente a api para obter se o status do job está completo.https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/elevation/api-reference/checking-job-status.htm

Comment: em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034091/how-to-check-task-status-in-celery

Comment: Obrigado Rafael, nao me parece que precise de tanto para o meu caso. No entanto obrigado pela partilha, o celery parece ser interessante mas não para a minha pequena escala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu desconheço que haja alguma solução padrão para esse tipo de problema. Eu posso sugerir simplesmente o uso de polling, tipo:

```
import threading
import thread
jobs = set()

def iniciar_job(dados):
    global jobs
    body = criar_body(dados)
    job_id = efetuar_post(body)
    jobs.append(job_id)

def download_zip(job_id):
    #use URLlib ou qualquer outro mecanismo para baixar o .zip
    pass

def checar_jobs():
    global jobs
    for job_id in list(jobs):
        if job_finalizado(job_id):
            thread.start_new_thread(download_zip, (job_id,))
            jobs.remove(job_id)

# checar jobs a cada 3 segundos
threading.Timer(3.0, checar_jobs).start()
```

Comment: obrigado pela dica do threading , minha implementaçao actual estava muito parecida só nao fiz recurso do treadhing , fiz um while loop que percorria a lista de jobs para verificar qual o finalizado , caso finalizado retirado da list e feito o download. 1x+ Obrigado pela dica do threading vou ler mais sobre o modulo para uma correcta implementaçao.

Comment: Você pode até criar uma classe Thread especializada que você instancia para cada job e ela mesma tem seu próprio timer para checar o progresso e iniciar o download do arquivo. Dessa forma nem precisaria manter a lista de jobs.